# multiselect column is not saving in the database

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, adminform

I have created my own module in magento with admin grids.In that admin grid form i have added multiselect options column like,

```
$fieldset->addField('category_id', 'multiselect', array(
        'name'     => 'category_id[]',
        'label'    => Mage::helper('bcpl_blog')->__('Category Name'),
        'title'    => Mage::helper('bcpl_blog')->__('Category Name'),
        'required' => true,
        'values'    => Mage::getModel("bcpl_blog/category")->getCollection()->toArrayCustom()
    ));
```

my collection looks like,

```
public function toArrayCustom(){
    $data = $this->getData();
    $items = array();
    if(count($data)){
        foreach($data as $item){
             $items[$item['category_id']] = array('label'=>$item['category_name'],'value'=>$item['category_id']);  

        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

now 'category_id' is not saving for multiselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid form inputs don't necessarily auto-save. This is the case with "custom" inputs where the `values` are derived specially, as in this case.

When you save this form, it goes to the save action, yes? In that save action method, you will need to parse/modify/clean/etc. the `category_id` POST data.

**In your controller save action**

```
$categoryIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('category_id') // input from the form
// Process $categoryIds
$processedCatIds = implode(',', $categoryIds); // JUST AN EXAMPLE; PROCESS ACCORDINGLY
$object->setCategoryId($processedCatIds);
```

Comment: I'm glad! Please try to upvote as well if you find answer useful.